# When you scale an element with css3, what transition-properties are being changed?

Tags: css, css-transitions, css-animations

Which css `transition` property is actually used when you use the css property:

```
.selector {
  transform: scale(n);
}
```

I'm trying to isolate which values are actually changing when I scale something with CSS. This works, but it is also animating everything, which I don't want to do. I only want to animate the height/width of the object:

```
.selector {
  transition: all 0.3s linear;
}
```

Instead of 'all', I have tried settings 'width height', but it doesn't smoothly animate anymore. It just snaps to the final position.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `transform`

```
transition: transform 200ms linear;
```

You need the vendor prefixes in that too like this

```
-webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 200ms linear;
```

I didn't fully understand your question but I'm guessing you just want to animate the scale and nothing else on that element, if so then this is what you need.